# preflight OPTIONS check gives 403 with Access-Control-Allow-Origin ”*”

Tags: ajax, laravel, apache, cors, xmlhttprequest

I have a single page app served on one subdomain and an api on another. I get a 403 Forbidden on the pre-flight check for an XHR POST to the api.

Debugging it in curl shows:

```
 curl  -H "Host: backend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com" \
 -H "Origin: http://frontend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com" \
-H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" \
-H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type" \
-X OPTIONS --verbose http://backend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com/api/users
*   Trying 54.153.79.158...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to backend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com (54.153.79.158) port 80 (#0)
> OPTIONS /api/users HTTP/1.1
> Host: backend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://frontend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com
> Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
> Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
< Date: Fri, 04 May 2018 21:16:52 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.27 (Red Hat) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips
< Cache-Control: no-cache, private
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, access-control-allow-origin, content-type
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
< Content-Length: 18
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Set-Cookie: 45fe47f0bb613513b8e98d0599b628f9=dd4b5c95b51d6168419458748b392421; path=/; HttpOnly
* HTTP/1.0 connection set to keep alive!
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host backend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com left intact
Origin not allowed
```

Yet the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the response suggests that it should allow the `Origin: http://frontend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com` named the request.

If I drop the `Origin` header from the request I get a 200.

I tried explicitly setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on the server to match match the `Origin` of the request but that also gets back a 403:

```
 curl  -H "Host: backend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com" \
 -H "Origin: http://frontend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com" \
-H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" \
-H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type" \
-X OPTIONS --verbose http://backend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com/api/users
*   Trying 54.153.79.158...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to backend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com (54.153.79.158) port 80 (#0)
> OPTIONS /api/users HTTP/1.1
> Host: backend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://frontend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com
> Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
> Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
< Date: Fri, 04 May 2018 21:32:52 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.27 (Red Hat) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips
< Cache-Control: no-cache, private
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://frontend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, access-control-allow-origin, content-type
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
< Content-Length: 18
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Set-Cookie: 45fe47f0bb613513b8e98d0599b628f9=a913ecc9ded73c3ac76fbb38d93e15a7; path=/; HttpOnly
* HTTP/1.0 connection set to keep alive!
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host backend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com left intact
Origin not allowed
```

On the server the .htaccess has the following configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://frontend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "accept, access-control-allow-origin, content-type"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

Setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `"*"` doesn't fix the issue.

Why is the response 403 forbidden when the origin seems to be allowed and how might I fix it?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is my latest `.htaccess` which is for the laravel PHP backend:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why are you returning a Set-Cookie response header to the OPTIONS request? That may be related... I've never seen an error message like `Origin not allowed`...

Comment: The api code that sets the cookie is a 3rd party Laravel code running behind a load balancer. It may be setting a cookie on every response for affinity. As I say in my question if I don't set an `origin` header it returns 200. That doesn't suggest to me that the cookie is a problem. URL that I am posting to is from the ”sign up” page to register a user. So the fact that it will 200 without the origin header makes me think it's a CORS issue. Why would a cookie interfere?

Comment: Hmm. I suspect that somewhere else in the backend code, the origin is disallowed. Either *all* origins are disallowed (i.e. the `Origin` header is disallowed) or only a specified set of origins are allowed, and yours isn't one of them. I'd check that 3rd-party Laravel code.

Answer (score 0):

As @roryhewitt suggested in a comment to the question this wasn't an apache .htaccess issue. The problem was the backend API laravel app was giving 403 to any CORS request.

I deleted the `mod_headers.c` configuration and configured the `barryvdh/laravel-cors` module used by the backend app using an environment variable `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=frontend-sjm-staging.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com`. This sets the `allowedOrigins` as shown [here](https://github.com/simbo1905/laravel-realworld-example-app/blob/5bc043fc37cd42865e7e6b074ad09de31c8bf6b3/config/cors.php#L15).